# How to append plots in bokeh?

Tags: python, python-2.7, bokeh

I have a CSV file that I want to plot multiple plots in the same HTML.
I want to use a `for` loop, since I don't know how many plots I'm going to plot, the number changes depending on the CSV.

This is what I tried so far with no success:

```
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
df = pd.read_csv("test - copy.csv",parse_dates=['MEASUREMENT_DATE'], 
date_parser=dateparse)
df.head()


for i in range(4):
p=figure(title="test", x_axis_label='date', y_axis_label='chart value', 
  x_axis_type="datetime")
  x=df['MEASUREMENT_DATE'][i]
  y=df['CHART_VALUE'][i]
  plots.append(p.scatter( x=x, y=y))
g_plots=column(*plots)
show(g_plots)
```

Comment: What is your error traceback?

Comment: this is the tracerback:
g_plots=column(*plots)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bokeh\layouts.py", line 147, in column
    Tried to insert: %s of type %s""" % (item, type(item))
ValueError: Only LayoutDOM items can be inserted into a column.
                Tried to insert: GlyphRenderer(id='d5ea754b-a03f-4ec6-a5d0-839441766b49', ...) of type <class 'bokeh.models.renderers.GlyphRenderer'>

Comment: found a solution. if you append twice it works. 
like this:
for i in range(len(param)):
    row=[]
    for _ in range(1):
        p=figure(title="test", x_axis_label='date', y_axis_label='chart value', x_axis_type="datetime")
        p.scatter(x=x[i], y=y[i])
        row.append(p)
    grid.append(row)
fig = gridplot(grid)